# How to track finger position with OpenCV

Tags: c#, java, c++, image-processing, opencv

I have a problem with image processing. I have set up a web cam on top of my laptop facing the keyboard so when i touch the LCD the image which get from the web cam bisects by the finger so my idea is to get the positions of the finger when it bisects the image. any help is appreciated (OpenCV, openframework or any other relevant framework)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like you want the hand to be white and everything else to be black. If yes, you can try simple thresholding (http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/thresholding) Try the HSV colour space to get a small hue range for skin color and threshold in that range.

Comment: thanks for the reply Utkarsh i have visited your blog before i found it really good i set up VS with OpenCV from one of your posts. btw i think this will help i will definitely give it a try thanks again.

Comment: Updated link: http://aishack.in/tutorials/thresholding/

Answer (score 0):

You can do object recognition with OpenCV. However, you will need to train an OpenCV classifier using Haar cascades and images of fingers first. All this comes packaged when you install OpenCV.

Here is a really good and detailed explanation on how to do this. They use bowls as an example, but you can use picture of fingers.

http://lab.cntl.kyutech.ac.jp/~kobalab/nishida/opencv/OpenCV_ObjectDetection_HowTo.pdf

Alex

Comment: thanks again for the reply but that's not i am looking for. may be my question is unclear. I have set up a web cam on top of my laptop facing the keyboard so when i touch the LCD the background of the image which produced by the cam become 2 parts by the finger.(like with CCV finger's blobs can be seen in white and background can be seen in black so white line bisects the black into two parts)

Comment: K so what you mean LCD? Which lcd? Is it a monitor? Sorry i dont think I understand your setup.